# Jquery html append prepend in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the following. Curently I'm having to generate the html markup using a number of steps. Been messing with it for ages but can't get the markup to work using as few steps as possible.

```
function prependCheckbox (data) {

        if (!data.element) { return data.text; }

        var $result = $('<div class="checkbox no-margin"><label>');
        var $checkbox = $('<input type="checkbox" />');
        $result.append($checkbox);
        $checkbox.prop('checked', data.element.selected);
        $result.append(data.text + '</label></div>');

        return $result;
    };
```

Comment: You're appending an empty label (and no, you don't fill it later).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is incorrect: jQuery can only build complete elements, not half elements. So `var $result = $('<div class="checkbox no-margin"><label>');` is adding an empty (closed) label and `$result.append(data.text + '</label></div>');` is just invalid.

If you're trying to put the checkbox inside the label, using the ability of jQuery to chain calls, you can do this:

```
function prependCheckbox (data) {
    if (!data.element) { return data.text; }
    return $('<div class="checkbox no-margin">').append(
        $('<label>').append(
            $('<input type="checkbox" />').prop('checked', data.element.selected)
        ).append(data.text)
    );
}
```

Comment: This is nice and short. Just need to remove end apostrophe typo from `.append(data.text')`

Answer (score 0):

I like readability and consistency

```
function prependCheckbox(data) {
    if (!data.element) {
        return data.text;
    }

    var $result   = $('<div />', {
        'class' : 'checkbox no-margin'
    }),
        $label    = $('<label />', {
            text : data.text
    }),
        $checkbox = $('<input />', {
            type    : 'checkbox',
            checked : data.element.selected
    });

    return $result.append( 
        $label.prepend( $checkbox )
    );
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/LLs5c4kz/)

Comment: @DenysSéguret - correct, I changed that to the more appropriate way of adding text to an element in jQuery